# How to specify which eth interface Django test server should listen on?

Tags: python, django, networking, ethernet

As the title says, in a multiple ethernet interfaces with multiple IP environment, the default Django test server is not attached to the network that I can access from my PC. Is there any way to specify the interface which Django test server should use?

-- Added --

The network configuration is here.
I'm connecting to the machine via 143.248.x.y address from my PC. (My PC is also in 143.248.a.b network.) But I cannot find this address. Normal apache works very well as well as other custom daemons running on other ports.

The one who configured this machine is not me, so I don't know much details of the network...

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:17:88:97:78
          inet addr:192.168.6.100  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:17ff:fe88:9778/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:441917680 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:357190979 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:191664873035 (178.5 GB)  TX bytes:324846526526 (302.5 GB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:17:88:97:79
          inet addr:172.10.1.100  Bcast:172.10.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:17ff:fe88:9779/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1113794891 errors:0 dropped:97 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:699821135 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:843942929141 (785.9 GB)  TX bytes:838436421169 (780.8 GB)
          Base address:0x2000 Memory:b8800000-b8820000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:1085510396 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1085510396 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:422100792153 (393.1 GB)  TX bytes:422100792153 (393.1 GB)

peth0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:17:88:97:78
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:17ff:fe88:9778/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:441918386 errors:0 dropped:742 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:515286699 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:199626686230 (185.9 GB)  TX bytes:337365591758 (314.1 GB)
          Base address:0x2020 Memory:b8820000-b8840000

veth0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

veth1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

veth2     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

veth3     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

vif0.0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

vif0.1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

vif0.2    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

vif0.3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

-- Added (2) --

Finally I used w3m (a text-mode web browser which runs on terminal) to connect from localhost. :P

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I think the OP is referring to having multiple interfaces configured on the test machine.

You can specify the IP address that Django will bind to as follows:

```
# python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

This would bind Django to all interfaces on port 8000. You can pass any active IP address in place of 0.0.0.0, so simply use the IP address of the interface you want to bind to.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't understand why two answers that essentially repeated mine got upvoted (while mine didn't) :/

Comment: @sztomi: The others had examples which concretized the abstract points. Using examples is an excellent way to clarify and greatly assists the reader.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if the IP of your interface is for example 192.168.1.2 and you want to run on port 8080, start the development server like this:

```
./manage.py runserver 192.168.1.2:8080
```

Answer (score 1):

No. It's not how it works. The interface has an IP address, you have a network with the test server and your PC. You should connect to that IP (possibly with an alternative port that you specified), and that's all. If you only have these two devices in the network, it is most likely that both of them should have static IP addresses. (or, if there is not mutual network, you cannot connect to each other).