# How to connect to vmware web server from windows?

Tags: python, django, vmware

I have a Windows PC with VMWare installed on it.

I have created a Django web server on VMWare (Ubuntu Server OS, Bridged Network, IP 192.168.1.7) and I can SSH to it from Windows PC.

My web server already run at http://127.0.0.1:8080/.

```
February 24, 2018 - 16:58:55
Django version 2.0.2, using settings 'fortress_of_mobile_phone.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8080/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

But when I tried to connect to this web server from Windows PC then I got the following error:

```
This site can’t be reached
192.168.1.7 refused to connect.
```

Could you please take some time help me to fix it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's your problem, it's listening on 127.0.0.1, you have to make it listen to 0.0.0.0 or 192.168.1.7.
Check here [How to specify which eth interface Django test server should listen on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188205/how-to-specify-which-eth-interface-django-test-server-should-listen-on)