# Not Able to access AWS public IP having all Inbound rules allowed for TCP connections

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to access my python-django web application deployed on AWS instances having all the In bound rules and security groups attached, but still I am getting connection refused error, not able to figured out the root cause.

I am trying to accesss
http://15.207.85.110:8000/
but not accessible.

I have also added the security group, but after that also it is not accessible, I have also tried after rebooting the instances. Am I missing something over here

**Application Up and Running**

[image]

**EC2 Instance Details**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your server is running on localhost (127.0.0.1:8000).

Comment: Try binding the app to `0.0.0.0` as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1188359/13070

Comment: Okay, it is working now, but I have question, my another java based application is hosted on tomcat on 8080, I am able to access that application without binding my server to 0.0.0.0, why I require to do that much stuff for python-django app